# componentDidMount to get DOM node got error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got error of TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of undefined
when trying to get offsetHeight of a dom node.

```
componentDidMount() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log(this.contentBody.offsetHeight)
        },1000)
    }
```

I suspect this is caused my async where the ref is not yet set. My render method look like this

```
<div ref={elem => this.contentBody = elem} className="content-body" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkupFromReferenceContent()} />
```

I tried to create a non ajax demo here https://codesandbox.io/s/j46o2656vy and it worked. That's why I try the setTimeout hack above, but no luck. Any clue how to solve this?

Comment: Its a binding issue in the setTimeout function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind `this` to setTimeout callback function. Like this:

```js
componentDidMount() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log(this.contentBody.offsetHeight)
        },1000).bind(this);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` reffers to the closest scope, so when you use it with a callback function `this` points to the callback function and not your object.

In EcmaScript2015 this can be fixed by using an arrow function:

```
componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(()=>{
        console.log(this.contentBody.offsetHeight)
    },1000)
}
```

But this syntax is not supported in the old browsers (IE in particular)

But if you need cross-browser support just use a variable:

```
componentDidMount() {
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(self.contentBody.offsetHeight);
    },1000)
}
```